# OrientDB, code gets truck in opening connection

Tags: orientdb

Trying to write simple test code with OrientDB 3.0 snapshot.

Is there a problem with this code? I do not understand why it get struck up there and never ever gets terminated.

```
@Test
public void testOrientDB() throws IOException {


    OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory("remote:localhost/mlm", "root", "password").setupPool(1, 10);

    OrientGraph db = factory.getTx();
    try {
        OSequence seq = db.getRawDatabase().getMetadata().getSequenceLibrary().getSequence("companyIdSequence");
        Vertex v = db.addVertex("Person");
        v.properties("id", "" + seq.next());

        db.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        db.close();
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if there is an issue with this test code

Comment: Hi, could send us thread dumps of client and server in separate gists? So we will see where it gets stuck.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/careerscale/0861a2543d2b1326533a5300e66755a4

Comment: server is built from latest develop branch of orientdb (needed the latest fix by Luigi)

Comment: How do I get threaddumb from eclipse?  the way I see is it gets struck at OStorageRemote.class at line 1274     
         `network.beginResponse(nodeSession.getSessionId(), false); 
        response.read(network, session);`    It never gets into response.read.. line.

Comment: to be specific, it is getting struck up at OChannelBinaryAsyncClient.class  line 203   `currentStatus = readByte();`

Comment: tried changing the code to use orientdb-graphdb  but no luck, gets struck at the same place. it fails if the server is down  though.

Comment: Ok, from an external evaluation it seems the problem is due to different versions of the client (3.0.0m1) and server (SNAPSHOT). Forcing both to use the same snapshot solves the problem

Comment: yah, thanks. it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an external evaluation we found that the problem is due to different versions of the client (3.0.0m1) and server (SNAPSHOT). Forcing both to use the same snapshot solves the problem

Comment: Yes, this did resolve the problem.Hopefully when the RC release is done, we dont need to go through this work around.